# Is there any way in spark to read from transactioned bucketed table before the compaction happens?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, distributed-transactions

I've a table in `hive` with `transaction = true`, and its `bucketed` and `partitioned by date`.
I want to query the table in real time while the data is being loaded (i.e. before the compaction ) . 
I am able to do this in hive, but in spark I am getting exception :

> java.lang.RuntimeException: serious problem

, Is there any way to query this in spark?

Comment: any solution you found for this ?